# Закрыть выпадающий список

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если список открыт то в классе появляется ***`active`***. Как закрыть список кликнув вне его?

```js
$('.menu').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu active">
  <div class="user-name">
    <?=$name?>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Войти</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Выйти</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: А как он открывается?

Comment: И с чего появляется класс `active`?

Comment: @Air   $('.menu').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
 });

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка, `править`... Отредактируй вопрос, добавь все наработанное и быстрее получишь ответ...

Answer (score 3):

Допустим так:

```js
let isActive = false;

$('.menu').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  isActive = $(this).hasClass('active');
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if(isActive === true) {
    let s = $('.menu.active');
    if(!s.is(e.target) && s.has(e.target).length === 0)
      s.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu active">
  <div class="user-name">
    <?=$name?>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Войти</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Выйти</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```